# Which statistical test to use to compare 2 groups of customers on >100 variables?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

Which statistical test/algorithm should I use to compare the customers from 2020-2021 (group 1) and customers from 2021-2022 (group 2). There is one instance for each customer in the data. There are >100 variables for the customers, like age, nationality, total purchase count, gender etc. Which test/algorithm can I use to be able to say, for instance, group 1 and group 2 significantly differ by age and gender and does not differ significantly by nationality. Group 1 has higher age compare to group 2 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! “Differ” in what sense? What about differences in how the variables interact with each other? For instance, what if the univariate distributions are the same for your groups, but one group has strong positive correlation between two variables while the other group has strong negative correlation between those same variables?

Comment: @Dave Thank you! Differ in terms of 100> variables, for instance, the hypothesis is that each variable is different for the 2 groups. We have to run some tests to find out which variables are actually different from one another and which one not? By difference I think I mean their mean values, but I am not sure. But to give a more specific example we can choose the variable age and check if the population age in the 2 groups actually on the same band or 1 group has higher age overall.

Comment: It will be important to carefully consider the problem you want to solve and what you want to learn from your data. If you care about differences in the means, that’s fine. If you care about differences in the variances (or some other characteristic) yet test for differences in means, however, then you are using the wrong methodology.

Comment: @Dave I understand, you are right. I was trying to get a general idea of what can be done. Would you recommend logistic regression, but I do not have a target in this case?

Comment: Sure you do! You have the group membership as a target, and then you can use the variables to predict which group is more likely. If some feature is a significant predictor of group membership, then the groups differ on that feature (with the typical caveats about p-values). The trouble with such an approach is that it still requires you to consider what kinds of differences you want to detect. If you care about differences in variances, you would use different features for the logistic regression (probably quadratic terms) than you would to detect mean differences.

Comment: @Dave I would accept this comment as an answer :) Thank you a ton!

Comment: I believe that comment to be vague and more of a question about what you want to do than a solution to your problem. If you have found it more helpful than I believe it is, however, please do feel free to post a self-answer. (This is not considered arrogant or out of line with the etiquette here.) An advantage to doing so is that, if you make a mistake in what you write in the self-answer, the community will see it and be able to point you in the right direction. (And if you make a big mistake that gets downvoted, you can delete the answer once you learn the right way to do it.)

Comment: @Dave Dave thank you, your feedback is extremely valuable. Once I try out a few things with the analysis, I will try to post an answer. I already tried logistic regression approach with target being the customers from two groups, as you suggested. But my data had multicollinearity so that did not work out. I am trying to clean the data and maybe remove high variance columns.

Comment: 1) So what if there is multicollinearity? What impact does that have on your work? 2) Why would you remove the features that have high variance?

Comment: @Dave I got an error using statsmodels package in python. The error was: LinAlgError: Singular matrix. I searched the error and read that removing high variance columns might work. I removed the high variance columns (columns with variance over 0.50), then the code worked, but only 8 columns are left and that did not give me much information about the customers in data

Comment: That seems like a reasonable Monday question to post.